# C# If string contains

Tags: c#, contains

I'm working in C# and I have 2 textboxes. If the user enters text in the first box and presses a button the text copy's into text box 2. I've now made another text box and I'm wanting it to show all the strings that contain @ if the user has entered them.
For example,
User enters *"Hi there @joey, i'm with @Kat and @Max"*
Presses button
*"Hi there @joey, i'm with @Kat and @Max"* appears in textbox 2
and *@joey @Kat @Max* appear in text box 3.

Just not sure how i'd do the last part.
Any help thanks! 
.............................................................................................
Okay, so I decided to go of and try to learn how to do this, I've got this so far

```
string s = inputBx.Text;
             int i = s.IndexOf('@');

            string f = s.Substring(i);
            usernameBx.Text = (f);
```

This works however it prints all the words after the word with the @ symbol. So like if I was to enter "Hi there @joey what you doing with @kat"
it would print @joey what you doing with @kat instead of just @joey and @kat.

Comment: You have not used any of the listed answers methods?

Comment: Through trial and error yes, I tried using string.contains but it throws and error saying can't convert bool to string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) the string into an array then use [string.contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) get the items that contain the @ symbol.

Comment: +1. I'd give you another couple of upvotes if I could, for pointing in the right direction instead of providing the full answer for what is obviously a newbie question (if it's not homework). Nicely done.

Answer (score 2):

A simple RegEx to find words that begin with `@` should be sufficient:

```
string myString = "Hi there @joey, i'm with @Kat and @Max";
MatchCollection myWords = Regex.Matches(myString, @"\B@\w+");
List<string> myNames = new List<string>();

foreach(Match match in myWords) {
    myNames.add(match.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var indexOfRequiredText = this.textBox.Text.IndexOf("@");

if(indexOfRequiredText > -1)
{
    // It contains the text you want
}
```

Comment: The op wants to get all of the names containing @, this will only get the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions to find the words you search for.

Try this regex

```
@\w+
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the neatest soultion. But something like this:

```
string str="Hi there @joey, i'm with @Kat and @Max";
var outout= string.Join(" ", str
               .Split(' ')
               .Where (s =>s.StartsWith("@"))
               .Select (s =>s.Replace(',',' ').Trim()
            ));
```

Answer (score 0):

A Regex would work well here :

```
var names = Regex.Matches ( "Hi there @joey, i'm with @Kat and @Max", @"@\w+" );

foreach ( Match name in names )
    textBox3.Text += name.Value;
```